# XNA Masking Mayhem

Tags: xna, hlsl, shadows

I'd like to start by mentioning that I'm just an amateur programmer of the past 2 years with no formal training and know very little about maximizing the potential of graphics hardware. I can write shaders and manipulate a multi-layered drawing environment, but I've basically stuck to minimalist pixel shaders.

I'm working on putting dynamic point light shadows in my 2d sidescroller, and have had it working to a reasonable degree. Just chucking it in without working on serious optimizations outside of basic culling, I can get 50 lights or so onscreen at once and still hover around 100 fps.

The only issue is that I'm on a very high end machine and would like to target the game at as many platforms I can, low and high end. The way I'm doing shadows involves a lot of masking before I can finally draw the light to my light layer.

Basically, my technique to achieveing such shadows is as follows.

See pics in this album

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yONK5.jpg

1. The dark gray represents the background tiles, the light gray represents the foreground tiles, and the yellow represents the shadow-emitting foreground tile.
2. I'll draw the light using a radial gradient and a color of choice
3. I'll then exclude light from the mask by drawing some geometry extending through the tile from my point light. I actually don't mask the light yet at this point, but I'm just illustrating the technique in this image
4. Finally, I'll re-include the foreground layer in my mask, as I only want shadows to collect on the background layer and finally multiply the light with it's mask to the light layer

My question is simple -
How can I go about reducing the amount of render target switches I need to do to achieve the following:

a. Draw mask to exclude shadows from the foreground to it's own target once per frame

b. For each light that emits shadows,

-Begin light mask as full white

-Render shadow geometry as transparent with an opaque blendmode to eliminate shadowed areas from the mask

-Render foreground mask back over the light mask to reintroduce light to the foreground

c. Multiply light texture with it's individual mask to the main light layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a polygon that captures everywhere the light can reach. Drawing a light (with shadows) then only requires one draw call and no render target switches.

The basic set-up is:

- Draw everything than can be lit
- For each light
- - Compute the polygon of where the light can reach
- - Draw the polygon using additive blending

I've wrote a small article, with a video, about how I implemented it which you can read [here](http://roy-t.nl/index.php/2014/02/27/2d-lighting-and-shadows-preview/)

The most important resource I used was [this beautiful tutorial](http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/) with interactive examples.

With this approach I was able to draw hundreds of lights (and smooth hem) at interactive rates.

Another (more sophisticated) example you can look at is [this tutorial](http://www.catalinzima.com/xna/samples/shader-based-dynamic-2d-smooth-shadows/) by one of the XNA MVPs

*Disclosure: first article is on my personal blog*